# Ordering a query on a field in a return record

Tags: postgresql, record, plpgsql

I've got a query that calls a function in its select clause. The function returns a record type. In the calling query, I want to order by one of the fields in the returned record and if possible I'd also like to return the fields of the record as fields of the calling query. To make this clear, here's a simplified version of the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getStatus(lastContact timestamptz, lastAlTime timestamptz, lastGps timestamptz, out status varchar, out toelichting varchar, out colorLevel integer)
    RETURNS record AS
    $BODY$
        BEGIN
            status      := 'controle_status_ok';
            toelichting := '';
            colorLevel  := 3;
        END
    $BODY$
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
        COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION DMI_Controle_getStatus(timestamptz, timestamptz, timestamptz, out varchar, out varchar, out integer) OWNER TO xyz;
```

Using this function, I want to have a query like this one:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    getStatus(tabel3.lastcontact, tabel4.lastchanged, tabel5.lastfound) as status
FROM
    tabel1
    left join tabel2 on ...
    left join tabel3 on ...
    left join tabel4 on ...
    left join tabel5 on ...
ORDER BY
    status
```

Postgres comes with the following error:

> ERROR:  could not identify an ordering operator for type record
>
> HINT: Use an explicit ordering operator or modify the query.

The question: how should I order by the value of colorLevel that's been returned by getStatus?

Additional question: can I return the three fields of the getStatus function at fields of the query that calls the getStatus function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ORDER BY (status).colorlevel
```

to reference a column of your record type.

As an aside: I used lower case(`colorlevel` instead of `colorLevel`) because identifiers are cast to lower case if not double-quoted anyway, and using mixed case identifiers is generally a bad idea in PostgreSQL.

---

As to your **additional question**, similar syntax requirement. I also use a subquery to optimize the query:

```
SELECT id
     , name
     , (x.status).status
     , (x.status).toelichting
     , (x.status).colorLevel
FROM   tabel
     , (SELECT getStatus(now(), now(), now()) as status) x
ORDER  BY (x.status).colorlevel
```

Read about [accessing composite types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rowtypes.html#AEN7249) in the manual.

---

#### Answer after additional input

To use columns from your tables, put it all in the a subquery. I am trying to avoid to call the function multiple times, because that may be expensive.

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    (status).status,
    (status).toelichting,
    (status).colorLevel
FROM (
    SELECT
      id,
      name,
      getStatus(tabel3.lastcontact, tabel4.lastchanged, tabel5.lastfound) as status
    FROM
     tabel1
     left join tabel2 on ...
     left join tabel3 on ...
     left join tabel4 on ...
     left join tabel5 on ...
    ) x
ORDER BY
    (status).colorlevel
```

Comment: Status is a reserved word, i changed it into 'order by (statusje).colorlevel' and now, I get an error 'column "statusje" does not exist.

Comment: @Leonard: `status` isn't a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Neither in PostgreSQL nor in the SQL standard. You may have created an ambiguity because you used the identifier on two levels: for the composite type and for an element. My query should work, though.

Comment: Sigh. I showed you a simplified query, but the original query uses fields from the query as input for the function, I changed the example to reflect this. The parser now says 'subquery in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level' if I place the call to the function after all the joins. It says 'column "lastcontact" does not exist' if I place it directly after 'from tabel1', which in my opinion cannot be right anyway.

Comment: @Leonard: no worries, we get there. :) See additional answer in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your support :). It works like a charm now! A new week, a new day, a new thing I have learned.